# SQL Statement to exclude rows which match on certain criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table of Financial charges, that has data like this:

```
tx_id    tdl_id     tx_num     detail_type_name     charges     payor_id    orig_payor
73765    737650000  1          CHARGE               320.00      1019        MEDI_CAL
7395     739500000  1          CHARGE               320.00      1253        THIPA/TORRANCE
7444     744400000  1          CHARGE               350.00      NULL        NULL
7444     744410000  1          VOID                 -350.00     NULL        NULL
7498     749800000  1          CHARGE               225.00      1011        UNITED HEALTH
750023   750023000  1          CHARGE               225.00      NULL        NULL
750023   750023100  1          VOID                 -225.00     NULL        NULL
```

I need a query that excludes the VOIDs and their corresponding CHARGES, in other words, a sql statement that returns these records:

```
tx_id    tdl_id     tx_num     detail_type_name     charges     payor_id    orig_payor
73765    737650000  1          CHARGE               320.00      1019        MEDI_CAL
7395     739500000  1          CHARGE               320.00      1253        THIPA/TORRANCE
7498     749800000  1          CHARGE               225.00      1011        UNITED HEALTH
```

Excluding these records:

```
tx_id    tdl_id     tx_num     detail_type_name     charges     payor_id    orig_payor
7444     744400000  1          CHARGE               350.00      NULL        NULL
7444     744410000  1          VOID                 -350.00     NULL        NULL
750023   750023000  1          CHARGE               225.00      NULL        NULL
750023   750023100  1          VOID                 -225.00     NULL        NULL
```

I first tried to compare the tdl_id using a statement like:

```
 SELECT * FROM tablename
 WHERE LEFT(TDL_ID,4) IN (SELECT LEFT(TDL_ID,4)
               FROM tablename
               GROUP BY LEFT(TDL_ID,4)
               HAVING COUNT(*) < 2)
```

But that didn't pan out because some tdl_ids have 4 numbers the same, some 5, some 6, and some 7.

My second idea was to compare 2 rows and look at the 'detail_type_name' and 'charges', such that I would compare two rows and if the 'CHARGES' are the same, (one negative), and one row has 'CHARGE' and one has 'VOID'.  But i'm not sure how i can compare two rows.  I tied using the same table in multiple INNER JOINS (as outlined here http://bit.ly/1a70mc2), but that didn't give me the right results.  Any advice or direction is much appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
tx_id, payor_id, orig_payor are sometimes not NULL and sometimes not NULL.

Comment: is it a coincidence that all the lines with charges-backs have two tx_ids, and a NULL payor_id and orig_id? Otherwise there's your criteria.

Comment: Sadly, just a coincidence on the sample I put here.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a NOT EXISTS on any records which contain a VOID and where the `tx_id`s are equal?

```
SELECT * FROM tablename O
WHERE detail_type_name = 'CHARGE'
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM tablename I 
        WHERE I.detail_type_name = 'VOID' 
              AND I.tx_id = O.tx_id
    )
```

Comment: I could try this, only thing is that tx_id is sometimes NULL.  If this is far easier/more efficient than any other route, it's possible I could do an update to the tx_ids that are NULL, as they seem to always match the first 4,5,6,or 7 digits of the tdl_id.

Answer (score 0):

I think the safest option is:

```
select tx_id, sum(Charges) from tablename 
group by tx_id
having sum(charges)>0
```

That way, if you void half of a charge, it shows up,  anything which checks whether or not a void exists for a transaction will exclude those when it shouldn't